# segmentation fault on reading in a data file

Tags: c, arrays, file, file-upload, segmentation-fault

I am trying to read in a file of characters into an array of 64 characters. the file reading happens in `main()`

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char write_msg[BUFFER_SIZE];

    fp = fopen("test.data", "r");

    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < (BUFFER_SIZE-1); i++){
      fscanf(fp, "%s\n", &write_msg[i]);
      printf ("printing in the for loop");
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("Starting the main().\n");
    printf("in Reader, the msg is: %s\n",write_msg);

    pid_t pid;
    int fd[2];
```

I keep getting a seg fault and I am not sure what I am doing

Comment: Add a newline to the printf in the for loop so it doesn't get buffered. How far do you get before the segfault?

Comment: Problem #1: Not checking for "fopen()" error.  Problem #2: what is "BUFFER_SIZE", and are your sure "fscanf(write_msg[BUFFER_SIZE])" isn't going to exceed it?  Problem #3: What exactly are you trying to accomplish in your loop?  Read a character?  Read a string?  Read a line?  How are you controlling what's being read?  I honestly think you need to re-think your logic. IMHO...

Comment: trying to read a line into an array

Answer (score 1):

`fscanf(fp, "%s\n", &write_msg[i]);` should be `fscanf(fp, "%c\n", &write_msg[i]);`, you don't want to scan a string into a char.

And the write_msg should ends with a '\0', `write_msg[BUFFER_SIZE-1]=0`

Answer (score 0):

I see the following problem in your code:

```
fscanf(fp, "%s\n", &write_msg[i]);
```

You are attempting to read a string starting at position i that is moving within your loop.  It will be very easy to get a segmentation fault when i reaches the end of the memory reserved for the string write_msg.

Another recommendation:  Put a validation on your fp descriptor:

```
fp = fopen("test.data", "r");
if ( fp == NULL ) {
    /* Show an error and exit */
}
```

If for any reason the file could not be read, fp will be NULL and as segmentation fault would be raised.

Answer (score 0):

You're scanning a string, which might be rather long, into a buffer without limiting how many characters will be read. You shouldn't do that. You're then incrementing `i` by one, even though the string might be much longer. You should use `fgets` or `fread` to read the entire file into your buffer, since you really don't need the special features of `fscanf`, and those functions will take a length of characters to read. Or if you really really like your for loop, you could use `fgetc`, which does exactly what you think `fscanf` is doing.